# Extracting every n line from file including blank ones in bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk, cat

I am using bash to extract lines from a file as shown below:

```
for line in $(sed -n 3~6p  file)
do
    echo $line
done
```

However, I now that some of the lines are empty/blank, and these are not printed, thus giving me an output on the form:

```
line3
line9
line21
line27
```

I would like the empty lines to be printed as well, so that i obtain:

```
line3
line9

line21
line27
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this??

Comment: you used `~` correctly for every n line address in sed, but your output doesn't show it.. no matter the one you got or the one you are expecting.  does `line1` mean the first line? or the 3rd line?

Comment: @Kent You are right, now line3 actually means line 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `read` command to read input line by line:

```
sed -n 3~6p file | \
while read line
do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Reading the file with process substitution has other problems in addition to omitting empty lines: it reads all of `sed` output into memory, it omits all trailing whitespace, and it *splits* each line by whitespace. The last one means that if one of your lines contains the string `a b c`, it will be printed as three separate lines. The `while read line` idiom fixes all these problems.

Comment: Thank you, worked right out of the box! I would upvote, but I have a verry "bad" reputation...

Answer (score 3):

You had the solution all the long, just drop the `bash` for loop:

```
$ sed -n 3~6p  file

line9
line15
```

This `sed` script prints every 6th line starting from line 3. Bash isn't the best tool for text processing if you tell us what you want to do maybe `sed` can handle the whole job, if not `awk` certainly will be able to.

Comment: The OP is likely echoing lines for testing/debugging purposes. Ultimately he probably wants to do with `$line` something that cannot be done inside `sed`.

Comment: If you add the quotes around `$(...)`, you will get only one pass through the loop, which is almost certainly what the OP expected. The output appears correct, but the logic of your loop is incorrect as it stands.

Comment: @user4815162342 if can't be done in `sed` it certainly can be done in `awk` and I clearly state the `for` loop is completely redundant in my answer.

Comment: I just want to remind that `3,6` means from line3 to line6. not `every n line` OP may want to have from 3rd line, every 6 line..

Comment: I wanted every n line (3~6) not line 3 to 6 (3,6). Sorry if I was not clear

Comment: Some things can't be done in either sed or awk. For example, the OP might want to invoke an external command or a shell function with the content of the current line (empty or not) as the argument. This is what shells are *for*, and bash is perfectly capable of handling the task. The OP correctly used `sed` for stream processing, but was unaware of the correct idiom for iterating over its output.

Comment: @user4815162342 that is correct, I do want to invoke an external command :)

Comment: `awk` can't invoke shell functions, though. For all we know, the code is a part of a larger shell script. There is absolutely no reason to believe that the whole script would be more readable when ported to `awk` (or Perl or Python, for that matter)—combining the work of Unix utilities is what `sh` excels at.